Showing that $f$ is zero almost everywhere
There is one exam problem I couldn't completely solve:

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a $1$-periodic Riemann integrable function. For integer $n$, put
$$\hat{f}(n)=\int_0^1 f(t) e^{-2\pi int}dt$$
Suppose for some $N\in\mathbb N$, $\hat{f}(n)=0$ for all $|n|\ge N$, and there is some open interval $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in I$. Prove
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx=0$$

Here's how I started my proof:
Let $I=(a,b)$. Suppose $b-a>1$. Then there is some $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $[x, x+1]\subseteq (a,b)$. By periodicity,
$$\hat{f}(n)=\int_0^1 f(t) e^{-2\pi int}dt=\int_x^{x+1} f(t) e^{-2\pi int}dt=0$$
for each $n\in\mathbb Z$. Then by Holder's inequality and Parseval's theorem,
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx\le\left(\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2dx\right)^\frac12=\left(\sum_{|n|< N}|\hat{f}(n)|^2\right)^\frac12=0$$
Suppose $b-a\le 1$...
I don't know where to start at this point.

Let $\phi(t) = f(t) - \sum_{|n|<N} \hat{f}_n e^{i2 \pi nt}$, note that $\phi$ is also Riemann integrable and $1$-periodic. Note that $\hat{\phi}_n = 0$ for all $n$. Since $\phi$ is square integrable, we can apply Parseval's theorem to get $\int_0^1 |\phi(t)|^2 dt = 0$ and so $\phi(t) = 0$ ae, or in other words, $f(t) = s(t)$ ae, where $s(t)=\sum_{|n|<N} \hat{f}_n e^{i2 \pi nt}$ ae.
Note that $s$ is smooth and $s(t) = 0$ for all $t \in I$ (since $f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in I$).
Let $z_t=e^{i2 \pi t}$ and note that we can write
$s(t) = \sum_{|n|<N} \hat{f}_n z_t^n = {1 \over z^{N-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2(N-1)} \hat{f}_{k-(N-1)} z_t^k = {1 \over z^{N-1}} p(z_t)$, where $p$ is a polynomial. Note that $p$ has degree at most $2(N-1)$.
By choosing more that $2(N-1)$ points in $I$ we see that $p=0$ and so $s=0$ from which we get that $f=0$ ae.

Can you elaborate why $s(t)=0$ for all $t$ and it is possible to write as $s(t)=e^{i2 \pi (N-1)t} p(e^{i2 \pi t})$?

@JohnDavies I have elaborated slightly.

By choosing more that $2(N-1)$ points in $I$ we see that $p=0$ This means it is possible to choose $t\notin I$ so that $z_t^0, z_t^1, \dots, z_t^{2(N-1)}\in I$ and $p(z_t)=0$?

No. Choose distinct $t_k$ such that the $z_{t_k}$ are distinct.
